# Publishing a generated JAR file to Maven using SBT

Tags: scala, maven, jar, publish, sbt

I have an SBT Project that creates a JAR file using some external tool (all working fine), i.e. it's not compiling source code. I have the Maven Repo correctly configured with correct Credentials but I am struggling to figure out how to configure the artifact so it publishes the generated JAR file.

My JAR file is "target/my.jar".

I've overridden artifacts as follows:

override def artifacts = Set(Artifact("my.jar", "jar", "jar"))

publish outputs the following

No dependency configuration found, using defaults.
[info] :: publishing :: org.foo#my-project_2.9.0

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this neat tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up the publishTo like this:

```
 override def managedStyle = ManagedStyle.Maven
 val publishTo = "My Repo" at "http://foo.bar/content/repositories/releases"
```

Then you run the 'publish' action. You can also do 'publish local'.

Comment: I did. It's actually pushing the "defaults" fine.